# Сервер разрывает соединение при подключении с linux (xfreerdp)

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2008-r2, altlinux

Есть несколько RemouteApp (среди них 2 .bat, которые не запускаются, сервер разрывает соединение).
Например, с excel все отлично.

```
xfreerdp /u:"" /p:"" /v:"" /cert-ignore /app:"||EXCEL"
```

Батник

```
xfreerdp /u:"" /p:"" /v:"" /cert-ignore /app:"||wingal"
```

Ошибка:

```
[13:59:21:721] [12203:12216] [WARN][com.freerdp.channels.rail.client] - [rail_is_feature_supported] have RAIL_LEVEL_SUPPORTED|RAIL_LEVEL_HANDSHAKE_EX_SUPPORTED, require RAIL_LEVEL_DOCKED_LANGBAR_SUPPORTED
[13:59:21:767] [12203:12204] [WARN][com.freerdp.client.x11] - xf_Pointer: Invalid appWindow
[13:59:21:768] [12203:12204] [WARN][com.freerdp.client.x11] - xf_Pointer_Set: handle=0
[13:59:52:235] [12203:12204] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - BIO_read returned a system error 110: Время ожидания соединения истекло
[13:59:52:235] [12203:12204] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - transport_read_layer:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRCONNECT_CONNECT_TRANSPORT_FAILED [0x0002000D]
[13:59:52:235] [12203:12204] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common] - Network disconnect!
```